# python pandas reindexing converts all data to NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(10,100,15).reshape(5,3)


df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = ["a","c","e","f","h"],columns = ["column1","column2","column3"])

df = df.reindex([["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]])

result = df

result = df.drop("column1",axis = 1)

print(result)
```

Comment: What is your question?  What were you expecting the out6put to be?

Comment: Remove the outer brackets in `df.reindex(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"])`.

Comment: actually I am waiting the output as the first ones which is a,c,e,f,h will be written as normal. And the other new index would be NaN.But  its not happening also I tried that with equal number of reindex with first indexes but it didnt work again.

Comment: when I remove bracket it gived his error:    TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys.I solved the problem.The mistake was the square brackets.In df.reindex part,I used 2 square brackets.But I should have use one.So thank you so much for your helps.